# Median with svy: command

Tags: stata, median

In Stata I want to know the median, p25, p75 and sd of my variables. The problem is that I need to use the `svy` command before the actual command so I can´t use lots of commands.

The normal command doesn´t work so I found on the internet the solution with the command `epctile`. The problem is that I need to install the command `epctile` and I can´t install it with Stata (via search ecpticle) because it says that

[http://web.missouri.edu/~kolenikovs/stata/](http://web.missouri.edu/%7Ekolenikovs/stata/) either

1. is not a valid URL, or
2. could not be contacted, or
3. is not a Stata download site (has no stata.toc file).

I am confused about this homepage https://staskolenikov.net/stata/epctile.ado
because I don´t know which I need to copy in my DoFile.

When I copy everything Stata just closes and nothing is installed.

Is there another page on the internet where I can install the command? Or is there another command with that I can find the median, p25, p75 and sd with the `svy` command?

Comment: https://www.statalist.org/forums/help#spelling

Comment: Find out from `adopath` where the program files should go: it should go in what is called `PLUS` in a subdirectory `e`. Then use the `copy` command in Stata to copy https://staskolenikov.net/stata/epctile.ado to a file of the same name epctile.ado in that subdirectory.